# iOS app that communicates with server by IP not domain

Tags: ios, server

Is it mandatory by Apple to use the domain name of my application server, or can I just use the IP address? Is my app going to be rejected by Apple, if I don't use a domain?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: @David It works perfectly, I'm just worried if Apple'll reject my app, if I don't use a domain!

Comment: You could sign up for a free Dynamic DNS account

Comment: Make sure you test your app on a pure IPv6 network.  Hard-coding an IP address seems to be very risky compared to the relatively low cost of getting a domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATS protection does not apply for resources loaded via IP address, assuming you are loading over HTTP. Attempting HTTPS will throw an exception (As HTTPS by design requires a domain and an accompanying certificate)